# list of entity values to get a particular value in thymeleaf

Tags: java, thymeleaf

I have a entity list value. but i want only three fields from that entity in the thymeleaf web ui. if i take the full object it returns the full entity value that i don't want to happen.

**My code:**

```
<li th:each="prod : ${menucataloglist.name}" th:text="${prod}">
```

Menucatalogist will get all the value from that entity i want to select particular name only from that list.if i try to do like this it throws error. even i'm not sure whether it is correct or not. Please help me to get this one done.

Answer (score 0):

```
<li th:each="prod : ${menucataloglist}" th:text="${prod.name}">
```

This should work.

Also, you could pass only the data you need from the controller.
So for example, load the entity you need in the controller and then pass three variables (`name`, `variable2`, `variable3`) to the template.